# Как конкатенировать последовательности в параметризованном классе?

Tags: scala, функциональное-программирование

Разбираюсь с полиморфизмом в Scala и не могу разобраться со следующим вопросом.
Например есть некоторая иерархия классов:

```scala
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
```

И есть некоторый класc `Foo`, конструктор которого принимает последовательность элементов и метод `push` который принимает новую последовательность элементов, конкатенирует ее с существующей последовательностью и возвращает новый `Foo`.

```scala
class Foo[T](a: Seq[T]) {
  def push[T](b: Seq[T]): Foo[T] = {
    new Foo(a ++ b)           // тут получаю ошибку - type mismatch; found : Seq[Any]; required: Seq[T]
  }
}
```

Но в моем случае это не работает и я не совсем понимаю почему `Seq[T]` кастуется в `Seq[Any]`.

```scala
val foo = new Foo(Seq(new C, new C))
val bar = foo.push(Seq(new B, new B))
println(bar) // должен содержать [C, C, B, B]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы перекрываете типовой параметр `T` в определении метода. `T` в `push` не имеет ничего общего с `T` в `Foo`, т.е. ваше определение приблизительно соответствует следующему.

```
class Foo[T](a: Seq[T]) {
  def push[U](b: Seq[U]): Foo[U] = {
    new Foo(a ++ b)
  }
}
```

И так как в этом случае типы `T` и `U` никак не связаны, ближайшим общим предком для них будет `Any`.

Но эту связь можно задать, указав на то, что `U` является базовым для `T` (либо `T` и `U` - это один и тот же тип).

```scala
class Foo[T](a: Seq[T]) {
  def push[U >: T](b: Seq[U]): Foo[U] = {
    new Foo(a ++ b)
  }
}
```